# nginx timings and 499 http statuses are growing up when http2 is enabled

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, http2

We have several virtual machines through which all traffic from mobile clients passes - downloading/uploading files, displaying preview images and regular API calls. There is no balancer in front of them, because requests are distributed via a virtual ip address. They themselves are proxies to backend services.

All this works fine on http 1, timings on average do not exceed 200ms, 499 statuses are quite low. When we enable http 2 mode on the nginx side, problems begin. The timings immediately grow up, rising to several minutes, the 499 http response statuses are increasing. At the same time, virtual machines do not use their resources even by 50%.

The problem is visible on both android and iOS clients, so we can conclude that something is wrong on the web server side, not the clients.

On average, one virtual machine accounts for about 300 thousand requests per minute. We have keepalive configured in proxied services. Additional settings that I spied on the Internet:

- http2_max_field_size = 512k;
- http2_max_header_size = 512k;
- http2_max_concurrent_streams = 256.

An example of a config.
We have about 20 such vhost per nginx instance.

```
upstream upstream_backend1 {
    server backend1.i:443 max_fails=0;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    server_name api.example.com;
    listen *:443 ssl http2;
    include inc/ssl.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass https://upstream_backend1;
    }
}
```

Nginx version is nginx/1.20.2

Actually, the question itself is: what could it be? Why does everything work stably with http 1, but when http 2 is enabled, chaos begins?

We increased the value of the keepalive parameter, changed the value of the http2_max_field_size http2_max_header_size http2_max_concurrent_streams parameters, but did not come to the point where the timings became at the same level as they were before, the same with 499 statuses.

We also fail to reproduce the problem in our dev environment, even if the stand is heavily loaded.